# Make 4 buttons take a quarter of the screen each

Tags: android, xml, button

I want my buttons to look exactly like [this](http://s3.amazonaws.com/kidzworld_photo/images/2010715/ffb289c8-ebf5-4846-97d8-aa86d13d80b6/foursquare200x200.jpg) but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried looking into different places on Google but none of the ways are like how I want it. I want to make my buttons have images and I was also wondering how I was going to resize these images on different screen sizes.

This is my layout_main.xml now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mudd.devin.drivenow.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="199dp">

    </Button>

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use nested `LinearLayout` widgets with equal `android:layout_weight` values. Or, use `PercentFrameLayout`/`PercentRelativeLayout` from the Android Support package.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options, the easy ones first:

1. `RelativeLayout` with a `View` in its center.

Put a `View` in the center of the RelativeLayout and align all the other Views around it (`toLeftOf`, `toRightOf`, ...)

2. Use a nested `LinearLayout` with weights.

Use one `LinearLayout` horizontal and one vertical, give your views width and height of `0dp` respectively and set all `weight="1"`.

3. Write a custom layout / `ViewGroup`

Just write a simple layout, assigning your views equal width & height in `onLayout`. This needs some more knowledge, but is the most efficient solution if done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layout_weight propety for setting weight of precent from the screen to view.

For example : [image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How would I make them all touch? I mean by taking the small gap out in between them.

Comment: You can use margin or padding in order to space between the Views.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you could just use a RelativeLayout, put a dummy object centered, and set the rest of the elements around that central point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works on previous versions, but in Android Studio 4.1, you can use constraintlayout and change these attributes of the button:

```xml
android:layout_width="0dp"  // match constraint
android:layout_height="0dp" // match constraint
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"   // 50%
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"    // 50%
```